# How to build a GUI to adjust markers on a python plot by clicking

Tags: matplotlib

I have a dataset that I plot using pcolormesh. There are bright spots on the plots, which I want to label with an 'x' marker. In addition to generating these plots, for each plot there is an associated list of coordinate 'labels' that are meant to correspond to the bright spots in the plot. The problem is, given the way that the data and labels are collected, the labels do not always match the bright spots exactly. What I would like to do is build a tool that generates the plot with the original labels, and then prompts the user to click the spot on the plot where they would like the label to be (if it is not already in the right spot), and have that save as a new plot and set of labels.

This is the function I have for generating the plots with the original labels.

```
def echomap_plot_rectangular(d0df, d1df, t0, t1, scan, save_to, keys, save=False, labels = None):
    """
    Inputs:
        d0df: pandas dataframe of data
        d1df: pandas dataframe of data
        t0: x values for d0df
        t1: x values for d1df
        scan: scan number
        save_to: path to save echomap plots to
        keys: list of frequencies (220000, 291000)
        labels: list of tuples of coordinates to label on the plot.
  
    """
    my_dpi = 96
    
    d0 = d0df.to_numpy()
    d1 = d1df.to_numpy()
    r0 = np.linspace(0,50,N)
    r1 = np.linspace(0,50,N)

    # PLOT
    fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(2*(ECHOMAP_PIXELS/my_dpi), ECHOMAP_PIXELS/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
    vm = int(np.maximum(np.max(d0), np.max(d1))) + 1

    im = ax0.pcolormesh(t0, r0, d0, vmin=0, vmax=vm)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax0)
    ax0.set_title(f'Echomap Plot of 50m (Long Range) Scan {scan} {keys[0]} Data')
    plt.grid()

    im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(t1, r1, d1, vmin=0, vmax=vm)
    fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)
    ax1.set_title(f'Echomap Plot of 50m (Long Range) Scan {scan} {keys[1]} Data')
    plt.grid()
    
    if labels is not None:
        # Unzip the coordinates into separate lists for x and y
        x_values, y_values = zip(*labels)
        y0 = y_values
        y1 = y_values

        # Add target markers to the existing plots
        ax0.scatter(x_values, y0, marker='x', color='red', s=250, linewidth=2)
        ax1.scatter(x_values, y1, marker='x', color='red', s=250, linewidth=2)  
        
    fig.suptitle(f'Scan {scan} Echomaps') # adjust spacing between subplots so `ax1` title and `ax0` tick labels don't overlap

    plt.tight_layout()
    if save:
        if not os.path.exists(save_to):
            os.makedirs(save_to)
            
        fig.savefig(save_to + f"{scan}_echomaps.png")
        print("saved")
        print(save_to)
```

It produces plots like the ones below. In the first set, the label is in the correct place, and so no adjustment is needed, however in the second set I would like to click and move the label to be on the bright spot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzVqi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/299wZ.png)

Comment: Why not just automatically place the marker at the brightest spot? Why would you want to build a GUI if it can be automated? Plus, the GUI will be imprecise since it can only be as good as the click accuracy.

Comment: Because depending on the data there may be more than one bright spot, and more than one pair coordinates, and this data is collected in the field and being labelled as part of a machine learning pipeline.

Comment: Okay, then, what have you tried in terms of implementing a clickable marker in Matplotlib?

Comment: So far, making this post asking for input. There must be some libraries out there but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: You should be able to do it in Matplotlib, but you're going to have to give it a shot yourself. Stack Overflow isn't a code request site and questions asking for software/library recommendations will often be closed as off-topic (see number 3 in the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Okay - that makes sense, will do!